# flutter textfield height decreasing when I input an error data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two textfield like this:

[image]

as you can see, the second textfield, which has an error, looks shrinked. those two textfields using the same code like this:

```
class GeneralTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? title;
  final String? initialValue;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final TextInputAction? textInputAction;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Widget? suffixIcon;
  final String? hintText;
  final Widget? prefix;
  final Widget? suffix;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final Function(String? value)? onChanged;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final Widget? prefixIcon;
  final BoxConstraints? suffixIconConstraints;

  const GeneralTextField({
    Key? key,
    this.title,
    this.initialValue,
    this.keyboardType,
    this.textInputAction,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.suffixIcon,
    this.hintText,
    this.prefix,
    this.suffix,
    this.inputFormatters,
    this.validator,
    this.onChanged,
    this.controller,
    this.style,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.suffixIconConstraints,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        if (title != null) title!,
        if (title != null) SizedBox(height: 2.w),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.w,
          child: TextFormField(
            style: style ?? TextStyle(fontSize: 12.sp),
            controller: controller,
            autocorrect: false,
            initialValue: initialValue,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefix: prefix,
              suffix: suffix,
              prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
              suffixIconConstraints: suffixIconConstraints,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
              isDense: true, // to set TextField Height
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3.8.w), // to set TextField Height
              suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
              hintText: hintText,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.sp),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade400, fontSize: 10.sp),
            ),
            keyboardType: keyboardType,
            textInputAction: textInputAction,
            maxLines: 1,
            obscureText: obscureText,
            inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
            validator: validator,
            onChanged: onChanged,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

so how to make the textfield height still the same ( I need to adjust the height when there is an error occured?

I think I just get this error after updating the flutter version to 3.16.4

Comment: Because you are provide height( `10.w` ).

Comment: I would also suggest, when creating widgets like textfields it is better to let them size itself. Like in your code, you gave a size to textfield which is not a good practice. Textfield will size itself automatically to the size of your texts and any padding if given.

Comment: It seems like you are using sizer/flutter_screenutil. I would say stay away from those packages. Most of the time, you do not want the ui to change proportionally to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by giving small height like in your code:

```dart
SizedBox(
height: 10.w,
child: TextFormField(
...
```

When TextField/TextFormField has an errorText, it's text below the input and it's space between text and input occupy spaces from it's parent.
In your case you gave them `10.w` hieght so inputs widget size get decrease.

Suggestion:

1. Give them bigger size like `64` or `48`
2. Handle error text with your custom widget. like below code:

```
Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [
     TextFormField(
      ...
     ),
     SizedBox(height: 4.h),
     if (hasError) TextInputErrorWidget(errorText: errorText!)
 ]
 ...
```